# Set TabBar item selected

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios5

How can i set a Tabbar item (with tag 0,1,2 or 3) programmatically 'selected' when an user opens a view controller with Tabbar?

i tried     `[tabBar setSelectedItem:[tabBar.items objectAtIndex:2]];` in viewdidload and -

```
(void)tabBar:(UITabBar *)tabBar didSelectItem:(UITabBarItem *)item {
```

but it didn't work, does anyone know how i can set a item on selected?

Answer (score 0):

I assume that tabBar is an outlet to a tab bar -- if that's the case, I think you need to use self.tabBar to have the change be propagated through to the UI (makes the change KVO compliant).